# Bounty hunter hat does not work when question is put on hold - bug?

Tags: support, bounties, winter-bash-2013, on-hold

The [bounty hunter](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/bounty-hunter) hat for Winter bash 2013 isn't given when the question is put `on-hold`.

It happens for this question: [Why do I need a tokenizer for each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314506/why-do-i-need-a-tokenizer-for-each-language)

For this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/610569/alvas#winter-bash (i.e. me =) )

**Why? and should the hat be given? Is it a bug?**

Comment: Did you actually win the bounty? Doesn't look like you were ever awarded it.

Comment: lolz, this page says so: http://stackoverflow.com/users/610569/alvas?tab=reputation

Comment: Ah right. There is no `+100` next to the answer either (as usually shown). Hence me wondering.

Comment: ahahahaa, a self-created hack =)

Comment: I think the user, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/users/610569/alvas, put up the bounty for the question and the questions gets put on-hold. So the points returned to the user but bounty isn't awarded but he is also the answerer with the most votes. LOLZ...

Comment: It looks like a moderator cancelled the bounty and returned it to the one who put it up to close the question.

Comment: You can never "win" your own bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no hat for **starting** a bounty.

The two bounty related hats are:

1. [Bounty Hunter](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/bounty-hunter): **win** a bounty
2. [Make It Rain](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/make-it-rain): **award** a bounty

When closing a question with a bounty, moderator must first "cancel" the bounty, it's not being awarded to anyone thus neither hat is granted.

Comment: @2er0 from this reply I understand you knew this and was just asking for fun?

Comment: nope, i was seriously wondering for at least 15 mins before figuring out what really happened because i saw `+100` and `bounty` and `on-hold` and no hat so i thought they don't sort of relate.